# Active record in standalone Ruby

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have standalone Ruby application and want to use it with active record gem. I've made 3 models:
user.rb

```
require 'active_record'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments

  validates :name, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :name, :state
end
```

post.rb

```
require 'active_record'

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :title, :length => { :in => 6..40 }

  attr_accessible :title, :content
end
```

comment.rb

```
require 'active_record'

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :content, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
end
```

Now I want to populate database with one user, one post and one comment for this post and user by issuing this code:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'
require './models/user'
require './models/post'
require './models/comment'

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML::load(IO.read('config/database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("development")

user1 = User.create name: "Joe",   state: "England"

post1 = user1.posts.create title: "RoR introduction", content: "RoR intro."

comment1 = post1.comments.create content: "This is great article!"
```

But now it populates database but user_id is null. What am I missing here?

Comment: For which record? The post- or comment record? Or both?

Comment: So you're saying that the `users` table in the database has one record with `name` of `"Joe"` and the `state` column has `"England"` but the `id` column is null?

Comment: @Stobbej, for comments table.

Comment: Does passing along the user work?
comment1 = post1.comments.create(content: "This is great article!", user: user1)

Comment: @Stobbej, it's same, nill in object, null in database.

Comment: This is good for using classes for your models. I'm looking for answers on how to get a SQLite3 database configured using ActiveRecord::Tasks. So far I can create the database with SQLiteDatabaseTasks.create but now I want to use schema.rb Have you tried doing any of that outside of Rails? Please point me in the right posts here if there is any relevant to this. api docs don't always have complete info on how to use something. Thanks and if I should post a question or not and how to phrase it clearly.

Comment: Don't you have to save it all to a db or are attr_accessible doing that? Does comment1.save work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your comment gets associated with a post, and not a user ...

just say do `comment1.user = user1` and then `comment1.save!`

I think the key issue here is that the user making the comment is not necessarily the user who made the original post.  If that were the case you could enforce it via the through option.  However since a post may be commented upon by any user, then saying post1.comments.create etc. shouldn't automatically pull in the user who created the post right?  Since it might be another user ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think you want those attr_accessible specifications in an active record class - I think they are interfering with the fields that active record provides automatically - try removing all of them