# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError after upgrade from Rails 3.2.7 to 3.2.21 and Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

I just upgraded an old app from Rails `3.2.7` to `3.2.21`, and from Ruby `1.9.3` to `2.0.0`, and I got the following error when trying out the app:

```
Started PUT "/books/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-20 16:15:10 -0800 
Processing by BooksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"mXizjcxG5Yq0BYG9vvvuqjW6O3/KhG6fUkoEeU6ORP8=", 
  "book"=>{"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421799301.062898"=>{"content_id"=>"16"}}}, 
  "commit"=>"Add selected content", "id"=>"17"} 

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: new_book_item_attributes):
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:70:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:69:in `update'
```

Here is my relevant code:

**books_controller.rb:69**

```
if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
```

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible ... :new_book_item_attributes

def new_book_item_attributes=(attributes)
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    book_items.build(skip_over_time(attribute))
  end
end
```

I looked through every blog entry in http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/ from *Rails 3.2.8.rc1 has been released!* to *Rails 3.2.21, 4.0.12, and 4.1.8 have been released* and I did not spot anything drastic that might explain this issue. Anyway, this was a "patch-level" upgrade, so I would not expect any drastic changes. Any idea what could be at fault?

---

**Update**

- This problem does not occur with Rails `3.2.21` and Ruby `1.9.3` (it only occurs with Ruby `2.0.0` (regardless of Rails (`3.2.21` or `3.2.7`)).

I modified the code block identified by @xavier-shay as follows:

```
  puts "-1- attributes: #{attributes.inspect}"

  attributes.each do |k, v|
    puts "-2- testing k: #{k}, v: #{v}"
    if k.include?("(")
      puts "-3- true to k.include?(\"(\")"
      multi_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    elsif respond_to?("#{k}=")
      puts "-4- true to respond_to?(\"#{k}=\")"
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        puts "-5- true to v.is_a?(Hash)"
        nested_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
      else
        puts "-6- else"
        send("#{k}=", v)
      end
    else
      puts "-7- UnknownAttributeError"
      raise(UnknownAttributeError, "unknown attribute: #{k}")
    end
  end
```

Running this on Ruby `2.0.0` and Rails `3.2.21` it raises an exception on the parameters cited above:

```
-1- attributes: {"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}}
-2- testing k: new_book_item_attributes, v: {"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}
-7- UnknownAttributeError
```

...however, in another controller, (and obviously with different parameters) there are no problems:

```
-1- attributes: {"title"=>"test title", "subtitle"=>"test subtitle"}
-2- testing k: title, v: test title
-4- true to respond_to?("title=")
-6- else
-2- testing k: subtitle, v: test subtitle
-4- true to respond_to?("subtitle=")
-6- else
```

Running this on Ruby `1.9.3` and Rails `3.2.21` there are no problems:

```
-1- attributes: {"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421828430.9315462"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}}
-2- testing k: new_book_item_attributes, v: {"1421828430.9315462"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}
-4- true to respond_to?("new_book_item_attributes=")
-5- true to v.is_a?(Hash)
-1- attributes: {"content_id"=>"8"}
-2- testing k: content_id, v: 8
-4- true to respond_to?("content_id=")
-6- else
-1- attributes: {"book_id"=>17}
-2- testing k: book_id, v: 17 
-4- true to respond_to?("book_id=")
-6- else
```

This deduction points to Ruby, not Rails. Any ideas on how I should debug further?

Comment: How about posting the whole action where the error occurs?

Comment: What happens if you add an empty getter for new_book_item_attributes?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated my question with some debugging I did. Currently it seems Ruby was the problem - though I am not sure how to continue debugging.

Comment: There are two differences between your two controller's attributes: 1) nested values-->shouldn't matter because it's the key that is the problem. 2) Snake case name v. single name; or...long name v. short name.  Can you try changing the name of your virtual attribute to `x`?

Comment: I changed the virtual attribute to `xxx` and the problem was identical. Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is some context missing here that is causing the problem, since it's non-obvious from looking at what you've provided.

Here are some options for how to track this down.

- Find out **what code in rails is raising this exception.** Ruby makes this really easy. You can either remove your backtrace silencers (probably in `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`), or you can grep the Rails source code for `UnknownAttributeError`. As it turns out, there is only [one place where this error is raised](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L88):

  ```
  attributes.each do |k, v|
    if k.include?("(")
      multi_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    elsif respond_to?("#{k}=")
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        nested_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
      else
        send("#{k}=", v)
      end
    else
      raise(UnknownAttributeError, "unknown attribute: #{k}")
    end
  end
  ```

  From that, it would suggest that your model isn't responding to the method name correctly. You can add some `puts` statements here (use `bundle show rails` to find the location on disk) or play around with it in console to see what is going on.
- Figure out exactly **which patch release caused the issue** by bisecting. In other words, go to 3.2.15 and see if you see the error or not. Once you've isolated the version that broke it, you can go over a diff and/or changelog to see what changed. At the very least, narrowing this down will help others here assist you.
- Can you make a **minimal reproduction?** How much code can you delete from your model and still exhibit the problem? Can you reproduce the issue using a standalone ActiveRecord script? i.e. something like  [Active record in standalone Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930644/active-record-in-standalone-ruby)

Hope that helps, let me know how you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer - I am honoured that *you* answered btw, as I am familiar with some of your database work.. :) Anyway, I bisected my way to determining that actually the Ruby version was the culprit. (I happened to have recently also upgraded Ruby - I just did not think to mention it when I first posted my question.) Hence I downgraded from Ruby `2.0.0` to `1.9.3` and the problem went away. See my updated question - I am not sure how to continue further debugging. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any difference between ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 2.0 here:

```
class Dog
  def new_book_item_attributes=()
  end
end

d = Dog.new

k = "new_book_item_attributes"

if d.respond_to?("#{k}=")
   p %Q{-4- true to respond_to?("#{k}=")}
end
```

Note: you don't ever need to escape interior quotes in ruby.

Output:

```
~/ruby_programs$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

~/ruby_programs$ ruby 1.rb 
"-4- true to respond_to?(\"new_book_item_attributes=\")"

~/ruby_programs$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481

~/ruby_programs$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

~/ruby_programs$ ruby 1.rb 
"-4- true to respond_to?(\"new_book_item_attributes=\")"

~/ruby_programs$
```

Can you rerun your tests and use `p` instead of puts to output the strings?

And I get the same output under both versions of ruby for:

```
class Dog
  def new_book_item_attributes=()
  end
end

d = Dog.new

attributes = {"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}}

puts "-1- attributes: #{attributes.inspect}"

multi_parameter_attributes  = []
nested_parameter_attributes = []

attributes.each do |k, v|
  puts "-2- testing k: #{k}, v: #{v}"
  if k.include?("(")
    puts "-3- true to k.include?(\"(\")"
    multi_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
  elsif d.respond_to?("#{k}=")
    puts "-4- true to respond_to?(\"#{k}=\")"
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      puts "-5- true to v.is_a?(Hash)"
      nested_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    else
      puts "-6- else"
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  else
    puts "-7- UnknownAttributeError"
    raise(UnknownAttributeError, "unknown attribute: #{k}")
  end
end


--output:--
~/ruby_programs$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
~/ruby_programs$ ruby 1.rb 
-1- attributes: {"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}}
-2- testing k: new_book_item_attributes, v: {"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}
-4- true to respond_to?("new_book_item_attributes=")
-5- true to v.is_a?(Hash)
~/ruby_programs$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481
~/ruby_programs$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
~/ruby_programs$ ruby 1.rb 
-1- attributes: {"new_book_item_attributes"=>{"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}}
-2- testing k: new_book_item_attributes, v: {"1421825320.571702"=>{"content_id"=>"8"}}
-4- true to respond_to?("new_book_item_attributes=")
-5- true to v.is_a?(Hash)
~/ruby_programs$
```

Frustrating.  :(

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort in trying to help me out. I repeated the test with `p` rather than `puts`, and the only difference is that each line is quoted, and each inner quote is preceded by ```\``` e.g. ```"-1- attributes: {\"new_book_item_attributes\"=>{\"1421864036.491922\"=> {\"content_id\"=>\"17\"}}}"```